# HTMLUnit website testing

Tags: java, session, testing, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit to speed up the testing of some of my development projects and I would like the ability to transfer the session of HTMLUnit to a real browser.

So, HTMLUnit might login, enter some data click a button etc. (I have got all this code done) then I want that session to transfer to my browser at the state that HTMLUnit got it to.

Comment: So what is the exact question, regarding the transfer of the session ?

Comment: I need to get the state from the HTMLUnit "session" and transfer it to a real browser eg. Chrome. So I can see the test and check a few things. I am not even sure where to start with it.